# Replacing variable section in string

Tags: bash

I am having a long list of strings (actually files names) `$var` looking like this

```
p1035sEthinylestradiol913
p1035sTAbs872
p946sCarbaryl1182
```

Now I wish to replace the string, which occurs between the first `s` and the first integer `[1-9]`, with `R`. Hence the output should look like:

```
p1035sR913
p1035sR872
p946sR1182
```

I was trying something like this:

```
echo ${var/s*[1-9]/R}
```

But this of course will remove the first integer in the string after the `s`match and that is not what I want. Can someone help me out here? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the matched digit you could switch from parameter expansions like `${var/s*[1-9]/R}` to matching `[[ string =~ pattern ]]`. The matched digit could then be retrieved by `BASH_REMATCH`. However, you still had to do this for every entry in your list.

With `sed` you automatically change every line and keeping the digit is easy:

```
sed -E 's/s.*([0-9])/sR\1/' file
```

or

```
someCommand | sed -E 's/s.*([0-9])/sR\1/'
```

Comment: It looks like in OP's case it would be `echo "$var" | sed ...`